# Does there exist a function $e(x)$ such that $\lfloor xe(x)\rfloor=\pi(x)$

Tags: number-theory

Does there exist a function $e(x)$ such that $\lfloor xe(x)\rfloor=\pi(x)$,
 where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function.

Comment: yes, define $e(x) = \pi(x)/x$.

Comment: @mercio That not what I mean, I mean e(x) in closed form

Comment: No, nothing useful

Answer (score 3):

There is such a function $e(x)$ in a non-trivial way, if there is an explicit formula for $\pi(x)$. Hence let me mention two explicit formulas. The first one, given by Vassilev-Missana, says
$$
\pi(n)=\lfloor \sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{\phi(k)}{k-1} \right)^{k-1}\rfloor. 
$$ 
The second one is the analytic formula given by Riemann, namely
$$
\pi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}J(x^{1/n}),
$$
where $J(x)$ is defined by
$$
J(x)=Li(x)+\sum_{\rho}Li(x^{\rho})-\log(2)+\int_x^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t(t^2-1)\log(t)},
$$
where the sum runs over the non-trivial zeroes of $\zeta(s)$.